# regex find and replace between two tags in sublime

Tags: php, regex, sublimetext

Does anyone know how to go about doing a find an replace between two closures.

(e.g  I want to find and replace

```
{!! random content between !!}
```

to

```
{{ random content between }}
```

So basically, just changing the brackets and ignoring the content between them.

I would use sublime to do this.

Edit: To better clarify: I am looking to do both tags at once as some elements need to keep the brackets.

Comment: Find `{!!` replace by `{{`. Again Find `!!}` replace by `}}`

Comment: Thanks, yeah I am looking to match whole string and update at once. Some elements need to keep the {!! !!}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `({)!!|!!(})` and replace with `$1$2`. The capture groups capture the brace to `$1` and `$2`.

See [demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/kV5eI8/1)

Or capture what's in between: `{!!(.*?)!!}`
And replace with `{$1}`

[Demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/kV5eI8/2)

Answer (score 2):

try below code it will help you suppose $subject containing your formatted data

```
$subject='{!! random content between{!! random content between !!} !!}';
$subject= str_replace('{!!', '{{',$subject );
$subject= str_replace('!!}', '}}', $subject);
echo $subject;
```